# Problem involving object free falling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, projectile, free-fall

The problem is the following:

> Consider an object A which is dropped from a height of 15 metres, at
>   the same time another object B is launched in the direction from the
>   ground with a velocity of $v_0$ (unknown).
>
> Ignore the dimensions of the objects and air resistance, calculate the
>   height at which the two objects colide, if at that point (height),
>   object A has double the velocity of B ($i.e$, $v_A = -2v_B$).

I know that (correct me if I'm wrong, of course) $v_A = 9.8t$, $v_B = -9.8t + v_0$ and that $x_A = \frac{1}{2}9.8t^2$, $x_B = 15 + v_0t -\frac{1}{2}9.8t^2$ ($15 = x_0$, I'm considering that the referencial is the point at which A was dropped.)

I've tried to equal $v_A$ to $-2v_B$, but, because I don't know the value of $v_0$ I can't get very far. I'm guessing answering the problem might envolve finding $v_0$, unfortunately I've got not idea of how to do that.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: If your considering positive x to be up then vA=-9.8t

Comment: I would consider putting the reference at the point where B is launched, with initial height of A at 15 m, and acceleration negative. Then $y_a = h - \frac12 g t^2$, and $y_b = v_o t - \frac12 g t^2$. I strongly recommend leaving out numbers "until the very end"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know two things: the relative velocities, and the relative positions at the time of the impact. You have two unknowns: $t$, the time of impact, and $v_0$, the initial velocity of B.

That is enough. You just need to figure out what equations to solve - and you wrote in your question that you know the equations (but see the comments that were made regarding sign conventions). When you write down the equation for the height of A and B, and you set those to be equal (at unknown time $t$ when A and B meet), you will find an expression relating $h$ (known), $v_0$ and $t$.

Next, you write expressions for $v_a$ and $v_b$, and set $v_a = -2 v_b$. That gives you a second equation in which the only unknowns are $v_0$ and $t$.

Two equations. Two unknowns. Solve.